# Significance of resource in Resource Based Policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am trying  to understand resource based policy in IAM.

I understand :  it is attached to a resource like s3,KMS, secrets manager etc.

My question is what is the significance **Resource** in a resource based policy.

For example a permission policy for AWS secrets manager(https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/secrets-manager-resource-policy/)

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "secretsmanager:*",
      "Principal": {"AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789999:user/Mary"},
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here the Resource is * or the resource can be the  ARN of the secrets manager. (Is there any other value allowed in this case ? ) For S3 I can think of the root bucket or other prefixes.

So my question is what is the use case for Resource here ? Please let me know if I am reading it wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking in the [User Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/auth-and-access_examples.html), you can see:

> Resource: which secrets they can access. See Secrets Manager resources.
>
> The wildcard character (*) has different meaning depending on what you attach the policy to:
>
> - In a policy attached to a secret, * means the policy applies to this secret.
> - In a policy attached to an identity, * means the policy applies to all resources, including secrets, in the account.

So in the case where it is attached to the secret, it effectively has no meaning that differs from `*`, but it is when you attach it to an identity that it becomes more useful. Then you can give differing identities different action permissions on various secrets.

Comment: I just learnt something new, +1. Bit odd that they decided to have `*` mean the secret itself

Comment: Thanks @theherk. So in the case of permission based policy for secrets manager the possible values for Resource can be only * or the ARN of that secrets ? If that correct ?

Comment: Well, you could maybe use `*` in a part of the arn, but it wouldn't be able to match anything beyond the arn of the secret, and I'm not even sure that would work. All this to say, I believe your understanding is right on.

Comment: I will test it. Thanks for that again.

Comment: If I add a resource based policy so that the principal is `lambda-mylambda` has access to a SM secret, will I **also** need to add a specific policy to the `lambda-mylambda` so that it is allowed to access the secret? Of will just the resource based policy do the work?

Comment: Identity policies and resources policies are evaluated together, @pkaramol, and as long as there is at least one Allow statement that aren't contradicted by a Deny statement, the access should be allowed. At least that is my interpretation of the docs. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_identity-vs-resource.html

Answer (score 1):

Resource is the resource that the policy refers to. It allows for more fine grained control over policies.

Take an example-
You host several DynamoDB tables, each of which have multiple indexes. You want to grant users in group A access to some of the tables, along with their indexes.

You want to give users in group B access to a single table, but none of the indexes.

And you want to give users in group C access to a single table, along with all 3 of its indexes.

When you specify the `resource` in the policy for group A
`"resource": ["arn::<table-a-arn>/","arn::<table-b-arn>/","arn::<table-b-arn>/index/gsi1"]`

The resource policy for group B `"resource": "arn::<table-c-arn>/"`

And for group C `"resource": ["arn::<table-a-arn>/","arn::<table-a-arn>/index/*"]`

Another use case if for explicit denies. An explicit deny always overrides an implicit allow. If you grant full access to EC2 in an account with a policy with EC2 permissions with `"resource": *` but there is a single instance that you want to limit access to by the entity to which you are applying the policy you would also add a deny statement to the policy with `"resource": <some-super-private-instance>`